# Can I stitch and blend bracketed panoramas using Hugin, as opposed to PTGui (as shown in linked video)?

Tags: panorama, bracketing, hugin, image-stitching

ADPPro's YouTube video [How To Stitch and Blend Bracketed Panoramas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAIVqVusGAc) shows how to reuse the setting from one set of images having a normal exposure and apply the exact same transformation on the second set where the only thing different is the exposure. He does this so he can do his own luminosity masking stuff in Photoshop. In the video he uses PTGui, but I would like to do the same in Hugin if possible.

Comment: This question will work better if you summarise the linked video. You could use hugin to make as many panoramas as you have exposure levels and then take those into Photoshop to blend. I didn't watch the whole video so apologies if I've missed the objective.

Comment: The video shows 8 images, 4 exposed normally, 4 exposed for shadows. Stitching each group separately in Photoshop shows different alignment and by creating a template in PTGui on the first group and using it on the the second group insure it's perfectly align to the first. Can we do this with Hugin?

Comment: @YvesGauvreau I've edited your question slightly to try to make the question more explicit, without requiring readers to watch the linked video. I am unable to watch the video now, so I'm not sure if my edit is accurate to your intentions. Am I accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, you can just load all of the bracketed exposures into one project, do all required optimizations as you wish, and in the "Stitcher" configuration under "Layers" select "Blended layers of similar exposure, without exposure correction" (may vary somewhat for different versions). This should give you one independently stitched image for each exposure level, possibly in addition to other output files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but I want 2 separate images, one per group with the exact same stitching, stretching or whatever else done exactly the same. Each image group is pre-processed in Lightroom to insure uniformity.

The same should work for any group of bracketed exposure so one can blend those in Photoshop.

Comment: As the last sentence of my answer states, that is exactly what you should get. If you absolutely want to closely mimic the approach from the video tutorial, Hugin also has an entry "Apply Template" in the "File" menu. From its description that should do what you ask for, but I have never used it. Also, the approach I suggested is more flexible than the other one as it can accept some variation both in exposure and in geometry.

Comment: Yes I saw this apply template thing and maybe I don't understand correctly, but it is said it doesn't use control points established on the first group of images. This suggest I would have to realigned each group each time.  In the video, he does a bunch of manual and or custom stuff to get the output he wants on the first group and the PTGui template mechanism seems to dummely repeat the exact same step to the second group and I assume it would be the same for any other groups. Just in case, in a newbie with Hugin and I want to know if I'll be usable to save $100 or more.

Comment: So, I just verified that the procedure I outlined does indeed produce the expected output (for my test image set).

Comment: after reading your answer a few times and if the "Layers select..." part mean that my image will be group by exposure and then whatever I do to one group will be applied to each other group in exactly the same manner. Well I think I've got my answer. Sorry it took me so long to figure it out. Can you say what the etiquette is here? Thanks

Comment: Yes, essentially you should set up a project as if you were going to have Hugin produce the final output from all the images, but then you tell it to create a separate output image for each so-called exposure layer (e.g. -1EV, 0EV, 1EV). You can request this output in addition to anything else or as the only output.

Comment: Regarding etiquette, I am not very active here myself. As far as I am aware, it is recommended to wait at least a day or two, in case someone else provides a better answer. After some reasonable waiting period you should select the best answer (checkmark).